# how to use grep to parse out columns in csv

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, grep, zgrep

I have a log with millions of lines that like this

```
1482364800 bunch of stuff 172.169.49.138 252377 + many other things
1482364808 bunch of stuff 128.169.49.111 131177 + many other things 
1482364810 bunch of stuff 2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1 124322 + many other things
1482364900 bunch of stuff 128.169.49.112 849231 + many other things
1482364940 bunch of stuff 128.169.49.218 623423 + many other things
```

Its so big that I can't really read it into memory for python to parse so i want to zgrep out only the items I need into another smaller file but Im not very good with grep. In python I would normally open.gzip(log.gz) then pull out data[0],data[4],data[5]to a new file so my new file only has the epoc and ip and date(the ip can be ipv6 or 4)

expected result of  the new file:

```
1482364800 172.169.49.138 252377
1482364808 128.169.49.111 131177  
1482364810 2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1 124322 
1482364900 128.169.49.112 849231 
1482364940 128.169.49.218 623423
```

How do I do this zgrep?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on OSX and maybe that is the issue but I couldnt get zgrep to work in filtering out columns. and zcat kept added a .Z at the end of the .gz. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
awk '{print $1,$3,$4}' <(gzip -dc /path/to/source/Largefile.log.gz) | gzip > /path/to/output/Smallfile.log.gz
```

This let me filter out the 3 columns I needed from the Largefile to a Smallfile while keeping both the source and destination in compressed format.

Answer (score 1):

To select columns you have to use cut command zgrep/grep select lines
so you can use cut command like this

cut -d' ' -f1,2,4

in this exemple I get the columns 1 2 and 4 with space ' ' as a delimiter of the columns
yous should know that -f option is used to specify numbers of columns and -d for the delimiter.

I hope that I have answered your question

Comment: hi I've been trying run it but it seems to be hanging perhaps its my syntax: `zgrep  logFile.gz |  cut -d' ' -f1,3,4  > file.txt`  am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I think that zgrep should have another parameter to much the line you want so don't uset if you don't want to filter throw line.

"""" this should work:  zcat logFile.gz|cut -d' ' -f1,3,4   """""

 zcat work like cat but it's for gz file>file.txt

Comment: Here is the command I ran : `zcat logFile.gz|cut -d' ' -f1,3,4 >> file.txt`
I just get this error `can't stat: logFile.gz (logFile.gz.Z): No such file or directory`

Comment: try using `gunzip -c` or `gzcat`  instend of `zcat`

`gunzip -c logFile.gz|cut -d' ' -f1,3,4 >> file.txt` or `gzcat logFile.gz|cut -d' ' -f1,3,4 >> file.txt`

Comment: I think that the problem is common for OSX user you should look at this link 
 http://serverfault.com/questions/570024/zcat-gzcat-works-in-linux-not-on-osx-general-linux-osx-compatibility

Comment: this is another link you should have a look 
http://magnatecha.com/zcat-adds-z-in-mac-os/